# cover a given disc with smaller discs

Tags: geometry

Given a big disc with radius R (R is not unit) and a small disc with radius r (i.e., r<=R), I would like to cover entirely the big disc with N small discs (the small discs can overlap) such that N is the minimum number of small discs that can be used for covering the big disc.

Of course, I saw the disc covering problem here:
http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DiskCoveringProblem.html

However, the problem in the link only considers the covering of a unit disc and also in that problem the small discs can have any radius whereas in my case the small discs have fixed radius r. I also saw the disc covering problems in some papers where a set of points randomly distributed in a plane should be covered by given discs whereas in my case the whole big disc should be covered and not only a set of points. Does anybody has a clear answer to my problem or even some reference or hint? Is my problem NP hard?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: can't you just scale everything by $R$ to get to the case previously discussed.

Comment: In the discussed case the small disc can have any radius, but in my case the radius is fixed and given (r).

Answer (score 1):

You can scale the problem in various ways.  You can set $R=1$ and consider covering by disks of size $\frac rR$, or you can set $r=1$ and consider covering  big disk of size $\frac Rr$.  These problems are hard because even though the problem is symmetric, the best packing often is not.  To use the information on the Mathworld page, you can just look down the list until the required radius becomes smaller than $\frac rR$.  That gives you the number of small disks required.  [This page](https://erich-friedman.github.io/packing/circovcir/) gives figures up to $n=12$.  For large $n$ you will have a triangular grid in the center with something going on around the edge.  When $n$ is very large, you can ignore the edge if an approximate value is all you need.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. If I understood correctly the problem is NP hard, right? So it can have only almost correct solutions. In addition to the number of small disks, I am interested to know the placement of the small disks (the coordinates of their center) on the surface of the big disk.

One thing I thought is to tessellate the area of the big disk using the hexagons (the size of hexagons are calculated using the radius r of small disks) and then circumscribe a small disk onto each hexagon. Just not sure if it's is a better solution than the one you proposed.

Comment: The hexagons are the same solution I proposed, just expressed differently.  It will get you close.  The problem with small numbers is proving a particular arrangement is optimal is hard.  [Squares in squares](http://www2.stetson.edu/~efriedma/squinsqu/) gives a good look at what a mess it is.  I don't know if it is NP hard-I think of that in combinatoric problems.